# Best way to structure Activity/Fragment/ViewModel interactions

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-viewmodel

Here's the situation:

`ActivityA` uses `ViewModelA`, which implements `IPropertyProvider`
`ActivityB` uses `ViewModelB`, which implements `IPropertyProvider`

`FragmentA` is used in `ActivityA` and `ActivityB` and consumes a LiveData property that's defined in `IPropertyProvider`.

What's the best way to get a hold of the proper ViewModel in `FragmentA`?

Does this sound like a sensible way of handling activity/fragment interactions?

Here's my current `OnCreateView` for `FragmentA`. I don't *intend* to restrict use of `FragmentA` to `ActivityA` and `ActivityB` (hence the introduction of `IPropertyProvider`), but this was my initial attempt to get it to work.

```
override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
  _binding = FragmentABinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

  val viewModel = activityViewModels<ViewModelA>().value    //  <-- This is never null, and so
                  ?: activityViewModels<ViewModelB>().value //  <-- this is never used, even if the fragment is used in ActivityB

  provider = viewModel as IPropertyProvider

  viewModel.myLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
    // Do stuff with the liveData
  })

  return binding.root
}
```

Comment: If a fragment is used in multiple activities, then the best thing would be to give the fragment its own viewmodel

Comment: So then it makes sense to make a `ViewModelC` that goes with `FragmentA`? Does that `ViewModelC` get created/manipulated in `ViewModelA`/`ViewModelB`?